# Flexbox scrollable bootstrap card (vertically)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, react-bootstrap

I have troubles to create cards with scrollable content, if they exceed the screen height.
I use a flexbox to force `main` to fill out the entire vertical space which pushes the footer to the botton of the page. You may remove a part of the Lorem Ipsum text to see how it works. To format all cards, i use a grid with a breakpoint (breakpoint is not included in the example).

https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-browser-bjek0?file=/src/App.js

If possible, i don't want to check the screen size with javascript but use css instead. I don't need IE 11 support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello :) The best thing that I can think of is this;
You can control the card height with max-height.

```
.card {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 80vh;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.card-body {
  position: relative;
}
.card-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  z-index: 1;
}
.card-footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Looks almost right. I tried to use vh but the value depends on the screen size. This means, on some screens it will fill out the entire space, on some not.

Comment: Yes, exactly.But if you want, you can also automate it for each screen using vh for header and footer too.